# IE7 AJAX GET only returning part of response

Tags: jquery, get, internet-explorer-7

I have a application that I can't get working in IE 7 (actually, IE 10 running in IE 7 mode).

The problem appears when I try to do an AJAX GET request using jQuery. In newer browsers, the response body is something like 30 000 characters of HTML code, but in IE7 the response is cut short at about 4300 characters. I can't find any indication that IE7's response body has a limitation on its size. Anyone know what's going on? Even better; does anyone know of a solution?

The server side implementation returns an `ASP.NET MVC 4` partial view, if that is of any importance. The client side code looks something like this.

```
$.get(settings.url_root + "?" + params, // typically localhost/getData?id=1234&id=5678
      null,
      // success
      function (html) {                       
            // html is ~4300 chars, should be ~30000
      },
      'html'
)
.fail(function () {
      // display error message
});
```

Comment: I really think this is a Server-side configuration issue. Maybe the maximum length of the Response, the Server script timeout. Did you take a look? (And I really discourage you to render partial views using Ajax).

Comment: @gustavodidomenico Yes, you are right. I posted the solution below, and it is a server side problem, as far as taking into account what can be sent to IE7 can be considered that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the problem was not related to AJAX or jQuery, but to how IE7 renders certain characters. Upon close inspection, I found that in the response, certain lines contained the zero character '\0' which caused IE7 to stop rendering. A simple `returnValue.Replace("\0", String.Empty)` at the server resolved all of my problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading only relevant parts of the document using jquery `.load()` by specifying the id of a container. refer [jQuery .load() Usage](http://api.jquery.com/load/)